# Mysql selecting column as null if join is not made

Tags: mysql, join, null

I have 3 tables.

- First one is user table which references to contact.
- Second is contact row table that holds email addresses and references to contact.
- Third table holds information, how contact row can be used and it references to contact row.

In this case I'm trying to get record from user table and set emailaddress to it if it exists and correct usage type is set to it. If contact row is empty or if no usage type is not set, result should still be returned, emailaddress should be null in this case.

**Table1**

- id
- f_contact

**Table2**

- id
- value
- f_type
- f_contact

**Table3**

- id
- table2_id
- f_type

Whenever there is complete chain on records in all of these tables it works, but when Table 2 doesnt have any records or Table 3 doesnt have correct reference to Table2 it returns nothing.

- Table 1 always has row
- Table 2 can have one or more rows
- Table 3 can have 1 reference to Table 2 row

What I have now is this:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.*,
  Table2.value AS emailaddress 
FROM
  Table1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 
    ON Table2.f_contact = Table1.f_contact 
  LEFT JOIN Table3 
    ON Table3.table2_id = Table2.id 
WHERE Table1.f_contact = 1113 
  AND Table2.f_type = 2 
  AND Table3.f_type = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing sample data and desired output but you can try it this way

```
SELECT 
  Table1.*,
  CASE WHEN Table3.f_type IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE Table2.value END AS emailaddress 
FROM
  Table1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 
    ON Table2.f_contact = Table1.f_contact 
   AND Table2.f_type = 2 
  LEFT JOIN Table3 
    ON Table3.table2_id = Table2.id 
   AND Table3.f_type = 3 
WHERE Table1.f_contact = 1113
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a800/1)** demo

Comment: This nails it almost. It returns one row with emailaddress with value and null, depending case. BUT also when there is not referencing records in Table3, emailaddress should be null ALWAYS in this case

Comment: Desired output is: id => int, f_contact => int, emailaddress => null or string

Comment: Almost. This fails if Table3.f_type is set to 2. No row at all in this case.

Comment: I've posted a working sqlfiddle example. Change the sample data to show your problem, click `Build Schema` and post a link here.

Comment: Damn. You are right. My problem was that I tried to add some nonsense to the end of query and left it there. With copy/pasting your query suggestion, it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Move your conditions from `where` clause to `ON` clause

```
SELECT 
  Table1.*,
  Table2.value AS emailaddress 
FROM
  Table1 
  LEFT JOIN Table2 
    ON Table2.f_contact = Table1.f_contact  AND Table1.f_contact = 1113 
  LEFT JOIN Table3 
    ON Table3.table2_id = Table2.id AND Table2.f_type = 2 AND Table3.f_type = 3
```

Comment: This seems to return all the records from Table1, not the one with f_contact = 1113. Also rows with other f_types from Table3 is matched.

Comment: You only need to move the conditions for `table2` and `table3` into the join condition.  The `Table1.f_contact = 1113` should stay in the `where` clause. I would also (for clarity reasons) move the `AND Table2.f_type = 2` into the join clause for `table2` not into the one for `table3`.